# Find the version of a program using the hash

Tags: manpage, history

how could i verify that the man is up to date for a command with the hash?
[md5sum pwd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8Zz2.png)
[md5sum $(whereis history | awk '{print $2}'))](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AlQE6.png)
*man history presents:*
"The GNU History Library is Copyright (C) 1989-2017 by the Free Software Foundation, Inc."

[md5sum history explicit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKzI0.png)
and in the man there is not appear option to how see  the "version" from this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvdzO.png)

For the following I suppose that history is only a library?, but then what is the program that prints? or is it each terminal that consults the directories that history defines?

Answer (score 0):

Every time you upgrade your system new documentation is installed at the same time.

So when you type `man`, or even better `info`, followed by the command name, you should feel secure the documentation presented matches the command installed on your system.

If you are googling the command on the internet, then you have to vet the version numbers of the webpages presented to you.

Comment: Thank you very much!!! Why does this commando feel like heaven?